# viewing multicast mpeg ts streams in ubuntu 16.04 with either ffplay or vlc media player

Tags: vlc, ffmpeg, streaming

I have been trying to view multicast streams as mentioned in the title above, but all efforts gone in vain. Initially i tried to view the streams by disabling ufw, assuming probably firewall might have been blocking the traffic, but this did not help my cause.

I have a cisco 3975 switch which is perfectly streaming out the multicast streams. I am able to receive and play out any available streams on windows system, but when i connect the ubuntu system on the same interface of the switch it fails to play.

Can somebody guide me in finding the way to simply receive and view the content through applications such as ffplay and vlc?

thanks

Comment: btw i am issuing following command i term

Comment: btw i am issuing the command in terminal as:- ffplay udp://239.1.1.101:1026

Comment: in vlc player udp://@239.1.1.101:1026

Comment: The `ffplay` console output will be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse path filtering could be a factor. You can disable (to test)

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

it can be permanently enabled via /etc/sysctl.d/30-rp_filter.conf

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html

Answer (score 0):

Another issue, is routing, ffplay (unless there is a hidden option to force a particular ethernet port) requires the default multicast route to function correctly.

Set it like this:

```
ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth3
```

Query it like so:

```
> root@xubuntu:/# ip route
> 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth3  scope link
```